char** to const char** conversion not possible
There's a HTTP parser in C, here, and in the sample code they make a call to a function and pass a char** to an argument that's a const char**, and it fails to compile on Visual Studio.
int phr_parse_request(const char *buf_start, size_t len, const char **method, size_t *method_len, const char **path,
                      size_t *path_len, int *minor_version, struct phr_header *headers, size_t *num_headers, size_t last_len) { return 1;}

    char buf[4096], *method, *path;
    int pret, minor_version;
    struct phr_header headers[100];
    size_t buflen = 0, prevbuflen = 0, method_len, path_len, num_headers;
    ssize_t rret;
    
    while (1) {
        /* read the request */
        while ((rret = read(sock, buf + buflen, sizeof(buf) - buflen)) == -1 && errno == EINTR)
            ;
        if (rret <= 0)
            return IOError;
        prevbuflen = buflen;
        buflen += rret;
        /* parse the request */
        num_headers = sizeof(headers) / sizeof(headers[0]);
        pret = phr_parse_request(buf, buflen, &method, &method_len, &path, &path_len,
                                 &minor_version, headers, &num_headers, prevbuflen);
    // CAN'T CALL THIS FUNCTION BECAUSE &method is char** and the function expects a const char**


Error C2664   'int phr_parse_request(const char *,size_t,const char
**,size_t *,const char **,size_t *,int *,phr_header *,size_t *,size_t)': cannot convert argument 3 from 'char **' to 'const char **'

It's strange that the sample code doesn't even compile.

Is the question why C doesn't allow char** to const char** conversions or why there is a bug in some random Github project?

add proper header files "to be even compiled" and declare const char *method; at least

You need to declare method and path as const pointers:   const char* method; and  const char * path;. That being said, don't write : char buf[4096], *method, *path;. Instead write char buf[4096];  char *method;  char *path; which is far more readable.

BTW what exactly from the project does not compile?

All them dirty "language-lawyer" details:
Valid forms of conversions are determined on the "type pointed-at" level of those pointers to pointers.
We may first note that function parameter passing happens "as if by assignment" (6.5.2.2), so the relevant rules here are the rules of assignment. From C23 6.5.16.1:

Constraints
/--/

the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type
the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified
or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left operand has all
the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right operand;


Example 1 (plain pointers):
char* a;
const char* b = a;


The left operand b has "unqualified" pointer type. Meaning that the pointer type itself has no const etc qualifiers. If it had, it would have been written as char* const b.
a is a pointer to "unqualified" char, b is a pointer to "qualified" (const) char.
char and char are the same type so the pointed-at types are compatible.
b has all the qualifiers pointed to by a since the pointed-at type by a has no qualifiers.
So this is a valid form of assignment. No explicit conversions are necessary.

We may also note a detail from the cast operator in C23 6.5.4:

Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be
specified by means of an explicit cast.

So C allows no implicit pointer conversions what-so-ever except those listed in the above mentioned 6.5.16.1 "rules of assignment" constraints (void pointer conversions etc are also listed there).

Example 2 (your scenario):
char** a;
const char** b = a;


The left operand b has "unqualified" pointer (to pointer) type here as well.
a is a pointer to an unqualified char*. b is a pointer to an unqualified const char* - again, the qualifier here belongs with the type char and not with the pointer.
The pointed-at types are not compatible. char* and const char* are two different types.

And so this is a constraint violation of assignment and the compiler must issue a diagnostic message.

If such a conversion were possible, you would be able to modify a const object through a non-const pointer.
For example:
const char c;
char *p;
const char **pp = &p;    // invalid char ** to const char ** conversion
*pp = &c;                // Now p points to c
*p = 'x';                // modifies c which is const

